# Does WordPress include jQuery in admin pages?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress. For the settings page of the plugin, is it safe to assume that jQuery will be provided. This, indeed, seems to be the case for 4.0.1 but I want to know if there's any data on what version of jQuery different versions of WordPress include, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to enqueue jQuery on an admin page

```
function your_plugin_init() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
}      

add_action('admin_init', 'your_plugin_init');
```

Please be aware that the bundled version will load jQuery in [no conflict](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) mode.

This list the jQuery versions included in each WordPress version
http://plugins.twinpictures.de/wordpress-jquery-versions/

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to assume jQuery will be available on a normal plugin settings page. To be 100% sure your script can rely on jQuery, you can specify `array( 'jquery' )` for the `$deps` param of `wp_enqueue_script()`, e.g.:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'myscript',
    plugins_url( '/js/myscript.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'jquery' )
);
```

There's **no need** to enqueue jQuery separately if you specify it as a dependency, WP will enqueue the required script(s) automatically.

An unofficial list of jQuery versions included in WP can be found [here](http://plugins.twinpictures.de/wordpress-jquery-versions/).